# Find out the database connection details from an existing Zendframework project

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

I have a zendframework project. from this i want to know the database details. i searched the code for it but no result. From where i will get the database username and password from the Zend project ?

Comment: Usually it's in the config file

Answer (score 0):

Browse the `/application/configs` folder. You find a `application.ini` file where db connection details are stored:

```
resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = ""
resources.db.params.dbname = "myproject"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
resources.db.params.charset = "UTF8"
```